# How to add caption to img that is centered in both directions inside squared div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create image gallery for my needs. I have to display pictures with random proportions - 4:3, 16:9 ... . Basically I have to deal with both orientations. Here is code so far:
html:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://img.wikinut.com/img/gycf69_-6rv_5fol/jpeg/0/Best-Friends-Img-Src:Image:-FreeDigitalPhotos.net.jpeg">
  <div class="caption">
    lalalala
  </div>
</div><div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Bonsai_IMG_6426.jpg">
  <div class="caption">
    lalalala
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.container img {
    display: block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.caption{
    padding: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syh0tuya/) where you can see that image is centered in both direction regardless of orientation inside a squared div.

The problem is that caption takes the width of container but I need it to be as width of img. Tried adding another div between container and img but it also gets 150px width.

Answer (score 0):

### [Here's how you would do it](https://jsfiddle.net/syh0tuya/1/)

Remove the `width` from `.container` and remove `position: absolute;` from `.container img`

Comment: ok, but what if I want to have control over the size of container?

Comment: Add another div around the current container and control that one. You could also choose to put a `max-width` value on the current container

Comment: It is not that easy. I lose ability to center the image inside square. Here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syh0tuya/2/)

Comment: No you don't, you just need to apply more styles: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/syh0tuya/3/)